# Is gnome 3 is slow or my machine?

Tags: unity, gnome, 12.10, 64-bit

I have Dell XPS 15 i7 - 2360 with nvidia 525M (1GB) with optimus running Ubuntu 12.10 64 bit and have bumblebee installed for optimus. Recently I installed Gnome Shell to give it a try and found it sort of lagging under few scenarios though rest all is butter smooth.

1. When I click on Date gnome 3 it appears as if a second has elapsed before the        window is drawn. But others panel items like network or volume looks fine.
2. In gnome 3 when I'm on dash with (window preview) if I remove any of the windows   before the remaining windows reshuffle it takes about 2 seconds (noticeable clearly).

Everything else is fine in both unity and Gnome Shell. What is causing this slowness? Is Gnome Shell is really slower?

Answer (score 0):

1. I don't have that myself, but it may be some slowness in gnome-shell or in evolution-data-server (trying to fill the calendar).
2. I'm pretty sure that this is a design decision. The idea is that the windows don't reshuffle too soon, because you may be in the process of closing several of them. Then it is really annoying when they move away from your cursor when you were already moving towards them.